# uploading image in php codeigniter

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-3, uploading

I'm trying to upload 4 images, but I have a problem with their names. When I am saving images in my server, I save their names in an array, but it only returns the attribute of the first image and the rest is only the name (without attribute). Also, in the rest it only returns the letter of that index.

I'm really confused, why is that happening?

My file names are: *pictts.jpeg / picture.jpeg / adadas.jpeg / b.jpeg*

```
$img_counter = count($_FILES['upload_img']['name']);
$files = $_FILES;
for ($i = 0; $i < $img_counter; $i++) {
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $my_file_name = time() . $_FILES['upload_img']['name'][$i];
    $my_new_file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $my_file_name);
    $my_new_file_names = str_replace('-', '_', $my_new_file_name);
    $New_file_name = $my_new_file_names;

    $_FILES['upload_img']['name'] = $files['upload_img']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_img']['type'] = $files['upload_img']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_img']['tmp_name'] = $files['upload_img']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_img']['error'] = $files['upload_img']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['upload_img']['size'] = $files['upload_img']['size'][$i];
    $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_options($New_file_name));

    $upload_res [] = $this->upload->do_upload('upload_img');
    $error[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    $upload_data[] = $New_file_name;
}
```

Wrong result:

[image]

Comment: Please add code and any relevant data as text directly into the question.

Comment: move `$this->load->library('upload');` out of the for loop